# Data loss using mysqli_data_seek

Tags: php, mysqli

I run a query, and loop through it modifying one of the fields with the code below.  I only need the modified number for a short time, and do not need it to go back to the database.  This works correctly, and using the echos printed out the expected values.

```
while ($d1 = mysqli_fetch_array($d1_query))
{
    echo "Before: " . $d1['d1_name'] . ": " . $d1['d1_earn_rate'] . "<br>";

    if ( $e1['e_id'] == $h1['e_id'] )
        $d1['d1_earn_rate'] =  $d1['d1_earn_rate'] * 1.2;

    echo "After: " . $d1['d1_name'] . ": " . $d1['d1_earn_rate'] . "<br><br>";
}
```

Afterwards, I want to calculate the total of a subset of the results.  I use mysqli_data_seek to reset the counter to the first row, so I can loop through it.  However, when I do, it calculates the total based on the original numbers in the query, not the revised ones.

I have used msqli_data_seek previously with no issues, but this is the first time I have modified data in the results before trying to loop back through it.  I don't understand why I'm losing the data.

```
mysqli_data_seek($d1_query,0);
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < 15)
{
    $counter++;
    $d1 = mysqli_fetch_array($d1_query);
    echo $d1['d1_name'] . ": " . $d1['d1_earn_rate'] . "<br>";
    $total_earn_rate += $d1['d1_earn_rate'];
}
```

Comment: do not use this function. Learn arrays instead.

Comment: Assigning to `$d1` doesn't modify the query results, it just modifies a variable with a copy of the row.

Comment: You assign to `$d1`, you modify `$d1`, then assign to `$d1` again. Why do you expect any of this to change the data that is returned by `mysqli_fetch_array`?!

Comment: So if I understand correctly, mysqli_data_seek does not move the counter back to row 0.  It actually moves the pointer to the original $d1[0].  When I made modifications, I was making it for that particular instance of the field variable, which disappeared once I moved on.  Something to do with pointers and memory if I remember my old C classes.

Comment: @Common Sense - You seem to be following all my questions.  I found your comment too broad and less than helpful.  A more proper (and polite) response would have been. "This function is not appropriate for usage in this case.  Using arrays would be preferred."  "do not use this function" is short, borderline rude, and does not provide any explanation of WHY I should not use it.  "Learn arrays instead", while I can infer it is the reason for not using the function, it also implies that I do not know arrays, which is presumptive and rude.  This is a example constructive response.

Comment: @deceze - I assumed it acted like a static array until released, so I could alter values like I would any other array.  The description for the function states only "Adjusts the result pointer to an arbitrary row in the result."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be thinking way too deep here. The matter is pretty simple:

- the MySQL server holds a result set in its memory, the result of your previous query
- `mysqli_fetch_array` pulls the data from the MySQL server into PHP's memory and returns it
- you're assigning that fetched data to `$d1`
- you're manipulating `$d1`
- you reset MySQL's internal pointer of the result set and repeat the above process

At no point are you manipulating the result set that is held by the MySQL server, and you're always pulling data afresh from said MySQL result set via `mysqli_fetch_array`. Every time you call that function you'll get the unmodified data from the result set held by MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer.  I was unaware of all of that, but it makes sense and is clear to me now.